# PHP file download instead of execution - WAMP Server

Tags: php, wamp

I am using WAMP server to run my PHP scripts. I created a test folder in WWW folder and trying to execute PHP script using HTML form action. But instead of execution, Its downloading the PHP file.  What can be the possible reason?

Apache 2.4.9 
PHP 5.5.12

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
  Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### PHP Script ( uploader.php)

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Did you enable the mod_php?

Comment: Does phpinfo(); works?

Comment: you also need in your httpd.conf a line : `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Its already added in the file and phpinfo() does work fine

Comment: Can we see your php file?

Comment: please get here uploader.php file

Comment: @Franky238 I have just put phpinfo() in the uploader to check if its running.

Comment: so uploader.php is this file?

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file?

Comment: So if you go directly to uploader.php you get the `phpinfo()` result, but if you submit a POST request to uploader.php it downloads the file? That makes no sense to me. Are you sure you're viewing the same file as what the form is posting to?

Comment: Are you double clicking on a `.php` file from Explorer. If so **dont** enter `localhost/testfolder/script.php` in the browser address bar

Comment: WAMPServer comes pre configured, so all this rubbish about incorrect config is just that. Rubbish If you enter `localhost` in your browser and you see the WAMPServer homepage, then Apache is running amd PHP is correctly configured

Answer (score 11):

If you took the files from a cPanel-hosted site, check the `.htaccess` file in the web root folder of the files and make sure you disable this (could be similar, like php56, php71, etc):

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

like so:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
#<IfModule mime_module>
#  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
#</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was caused because the .htaccess file had this directive to run php 7 in the Joomla's directory (Old server allowed to use different PHP versions on different directories):

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

I Just comment them out in the new server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you submit your httpd.conf here? You can also try to add the following code to your httpd.conf file and restart WAMP

```
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the reason can be turned off "file_uploads" in your `php.ini` file. So go to your `php.ini` file and check if you have `file_uploads = On`

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I have to delete `.htaccess` file to make it work.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an actual solution, it's VERY unlikely this is a fix for more than a handful of people as the .htaccess file contains instructions on how Apache handles certain requests.

Comment: Thank you for clearing -1. I faced the same problem today and what I did is change .htaccess file. If it worked for me then it is definitely a solution.

Comment: Which is fine for your specific issue, but the .htaccess isn't the cause.

Comment: Here we just provide each and every possible solution because we are not completely sure which user is coming to this this thread with exactly what scenario. I share my solution only after its worked for me. Hence it is possible it can help other users too. If it is fine for "specific" issue then it is fine to be here :)